# How do you update Gnome Screenshot?

Tags: 19.04, gnome-screenshot

Version: 3.30.0-2ubuntu1
Source: ubuntu-disco-main

I noticed the latest version is 3.32.0 and that it removes the app menu. How would I get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go the ppa route.

Visit https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas and enter *gnome-screenshot* in the search box.

One of the hits is [this](https://launchpad.net/~jbicha/+archive/ubuntu/temp332). See the image below:

[image: gnome-screenshot 3.32]

As for trusting this ppa, [jbicha](https://launchpad.net/~jbicha), who is providing the ppa, is well-known in Ubuntu and GNOME circles and a long-time member of [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users/1579/jeremy-bicha) :)

Comment: I'll suggest to add a link for [PPA search](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=gnome-screenshot).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that facility!